# Why does netcore3.1 framework cause this error?

Tags: asp.net-core, build, webapi

I have an aspnetcore api project I wrote in .net core 2.2, and changed the targeted framework in the csproj file to .net core 3.1.  The project now has the following error (NETSDK1):

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package is not supported when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher.  A FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App should be used instead, and will be implicitly included by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets

The Nuget Viewer for the project has no such project listed, and the error is occurring in a file outside my project.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The original source code using .net core 2.2 is here:  https://github.com/rambotech/BOG.DropZone

Comment: Please, add important parts of your code in the question.

Comment: Did you update the project file? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30#update-the-project-file

Comment: The error message said `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` does not support for asp.net core 3.1.You could only use the package in your project with target framework asp.net core 2.2.

Comment: @crgolden  This fixed the problem.  The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All was buried deep down in the project file, and it worked when I removed it (and dealt with a slew of related NuGet updates afterwards).  Thanks.